# 'Gcloud beta app deploy' fails with timeout after 10m

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

After uploading all the files, it starts "Updating service" and fails after the 10m timeout. I tried setting the config to be longer than 10 mins but it still fails with the same 10m timeout error. Is there a way to fix this?

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Cloud build did not succeed within 10m.
Build error details: Build error details not available..
Check the build log for errors: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/81ce5ba5-c24d-4938-98ab-d5bc859898de?project=xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Can be [known](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131889237) issue. In that case possible workaround is:

> To build your container images outside of Google Cloud Platform, you
>   must first upload your images to a container image repository before
>   you can deploy your images to App Engine with the gcloud app deploy
>   command.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201696) solution for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help again, I am a bit new to Docker, what is my local image? (for this command docker tag :[SOURCE_IMAGE] [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] )

Comment: Check this (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) detailed guide. Also, if you not experienced in Docker, I recommend you to check all How-to guides (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling).

Comment: that is the page I am following, I am confused when it references SOURCE_IMAGE, is it a dockerfile I need to create? My project folder?

Comment: Hey, SOURCE_IMAGE is the name of your local image what you define while performing "docker build" command (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile). Please check this tutorial for better understanding (https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/).  You can see list of images with "docker images" command. Then use that name for tagging your docker (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-docker-tags-to-add-version-control-to-images/).

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I managed to figure it out and everything deployed correctly. However, I am getting cors errors when trying to query the API locally. I have added flask_cors to the application so I am unsure of the reason.

Comment: @BradleyB19 This is a new issue and new question creation will be the best option. Also, upvote the solution, to help other people find the answer!